# Parsing stdin for files provided by ls

Tags: c, parsing, unix

**TL;DR: Is the output of `ls` standardised so that there is a perfect way to parse it into an array of files names ?**

I have to write a program that processes some files, the program specification states this:

> Your program should read a list of files from the standard entry

And an example is given of how to program will be used:

```
ls /usr/include/std*.h | ./distribuer 3
```

Where `distribuer` is the name of my program.

From my tests, I see that `ls` separates the files names with tabs when called with this sort of argument containing a wildcard, is this behaviour standard ? Or might `ls` sometimes use simple whitespace characters or even newlines when called with similar wildcard arguments ?
Finally, while this might be an edge case, I am also worried that since Unix allows for tabs and whitespaces in filenames, it could actually be impossible to reliably parse the output of `ls`, is that correct ?

Comment: `ls` behaves differently depending on whether its standard output is a terminal or not. When it is, it defaults to displaying file names in columns (when not displaying longer information, such as file names with date, permission, and other information). When piped to a program, it displays each file name on one line. You can see this with `ls /usr/include/std*.h | cat`. File names with special characters can be a problem, but you can ignore this for a simple school assignment. For a thorough solution, you would need to traverse the file system with calls like `fts_open`.

Comment: Unfortunately, ls does not have a `-0` option (find does have it) , so filenames with embedded `\n`  need special care.

Comment: On macOS, `ls` does have a `-B` option to print non-printable characters as `\xxx`, where `xxx` is octal for the character code. On POSIX generally, the `-q` switch prints non-printable characters as `?`. Unfortunately, that does not contain information about the actual characters.

Comment: If you have control over the `ls` call, you could use the options `ls -mQ`. `-m` to display the names separated with a comma and a space, and `-Q` to put double-quotes around the name.

Comment: What do you mean by TL;DR in your title?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you ! Didn't knew that it behaved differently, that's interesting.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson This means "Too Long; Didn't Read", this is followed by a summary of a longer post.

Comment: @TrevörAnneDenise: Yes, it is an interesting “feature” for commands to behave differently depending on whether a human is observing them (output is a terminal) or not (output is a pipe or file). The robots aren’t anywhere near ready to overthrow civilization, rule the world, and subjugate humans, yet they have already gained subterfuge.

Comment: Too long to read for you? And for us?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: @ArndtJonasson For the ones reading :) Honestly, here, I don't think the question was that big but I often like to put it ahead of a question anyway to give some context, helps readers know immediately wether or not they can answer the question without having to read the whole thing.

Comment: OK, I don't get it - I'm probably too old.

Comment: @nbari Yes, honestly I don't like at all the "stringiness" of shell.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the output of `ls` standardised so that there is a perfect way to parse it into an array of files names?

The output of `ls` is certainly standardised, by the [Posix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html). In the section `STDOUT`, the standardised formats are described:

> The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output; the exceptions are to terminals or when one of the `-C`, `-m`, or `-x` options is specified.

As well as a cautionary note about an important context in which the output is *not* standardised:

> If the output is to a terminal, the format is implementation-defined.

(There is quite a lot of specification of how the format changes with different command-line parameters, which I'm not quoting because it is not immediately relevant here.)

So the standardised format, applicable if `stdout` is not directed to a terminal and if no command-line options are provided (or if the `-1` option is provided, even if `stdout` is a terminal) is to print one entry per line.

Unfortunately, that does not provide a "perfect way" to parse the output, because it is legal for filenames to include newline characters, and a filename which includes a newline character will obviously span more than one line. If all you have is the `ls` output, there is no 100% reliable way to tell whether a newline (other than the last one) indicates the end of a filename or is a newline character in the filename.

For the purposes of your assignment, the simple strategy would be just to ignore that imperfection (or, better, document it and then ignore it), which is the same strategy that many Unix utilities use. Files whose names include newlines are extremely rare in the wild, and people who create files with newlines in their names probably deserve the problems they will cause themselves. However, you will find a lot of people here (including me, sometimes) suggesting that scripts should work correctly with all legal filenames. So the rest of this answer discusses some of the possible responses to this pedantry. Note that none of them are "perfect".

One imperfect solution is to try to figure out whether a given newline is embedded or not. If you know the list was produced by `ls` without any sorting options, you might be able to guess correctly in most cases by using the fact that `ls` presents files sorted by the current locale's collation rules. So if a line is out of sequence (either less than the preceding line or greater than the following one) then it is appropriate to guess that it is a continuation of the filename. That won't always work, and I don't know any utility which tries it, but it might be worth mentioning.

If you were running `ls` yourself, you could take advantage of the `-q` option, which causes non-printing characters (including tabs and newlines) to be replaced with <kbd>?</kbd> in the output. That forces the filename to be printed on a single line, but has the disadvantage that you no longer know what the filename was before the substitution, since there are a variety of characters which could be replaced with a question mark (including a question mark itself). You might be able to query the filesystem to find the real name of the file, but there are a lot of corner cases I'm not going to go into since the premise of this paragraph is not applicable to the actual problem.

The most common solution is to allow the user to tell your utility that filenames are separated with a NUL character rather than a newline. This is 100% reliable because filenames cannot contain NUL characters -- in fact, that's the only character they cannot contain. Unfortunately, `ls` does not provide an option to produce output in this format, but the user could use the `find` utility to generate the same listing as `ls` and then use the non-standard but widely-implemented `-print0` option to write out the filenames with NUL terminators. (If only Posix standard options to `find` are available, you can still produce the output by using `-exec` with an appropriate command to output the name.)

Many utilities which accept lists of filenames on standard input have (non-standard) options to specify a delimiter character, or to specify that the delimiter is NUL instead of newline. See, for example, `xargs -0`, `sort -z` (Gnu or BSD) or `read -d` (bash). So this is probably a reasonable enhancement if you're interested in coding it.

It's worth noting that most standard shell utilities do not provide an option to take a list of filenames through standard input. Most utilities prefer to receive filenames as command-line arguments. This works well because when the shell expands "globs" (like `*`) specified on a command-line, it does not rerun word-splitting on the output; each filename becomes a single argument. That means that

```
./distribute *
```

is almost perfect as a way of passing a list of filenames to a utility. But it is still not quite perfect because there is a limit to the number of command-line arguments you can provide in a single command-line. So if the directory has a really large number of files, the expansion of `*` might exceed that limit, causing the utility execution to fail. `find` also just passes filenames through to `-exec` as single arguments without word-splitting, and the use of `{}+` as an `-exec` command terminator will split the filenames into sets which are small enough that they will not exceed to command-line limit. That's safer than `./distribute *`, but it does mean that the utility may be called several times, once for each set. (And it's also a bit annoying getting the `find` predicates to give you exactly what you want.)